# Expectation of Random variable and absolute values

Tags: probability, expected-value

For any random variable X, we have that
E[|X|] = |E[X]|.
True or false? Why?
I believe it would be false but Im having trouble putting it into words

Comment: What happens if $X$ is a non-zero, symmetric random variable?

Comment: It is true precisely when $\mathbb E\left[|X|\right]$ exists and  $\mathbb P(X \lt 0) \mathbb P(X \gt 0) =0$

Comment: Hint: What does Jensen's inequality tell us?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To show that it is false, we do not need an explanation in words (though this can be useful), but a single counterexample.

Since the modulus function has no effect with positive numbers, let's try the simplest random variable we can think of that has a possible negative value. For me, that would be:

$$ X =
\begin{cases}
1                  & \mbox{with probability } 1/2 \\
-1 & \mbox{with probability } 1/2
\end{cases}$$

$\mathbb{E}(|X|)=|1|\times\frac{1}{2}+|-1|\times\frac{1}{2}=1\times\frac{1}{2}+1\times\frac{1}{2}=1$

$|\mathbb{E}(X)|=|1\times\frac{1}{2}+(-1)\times\frac{1}{2}|=|0|=0 $

This is perfectly sufficient as an answer, but can you add to it: what would be an explanation in words for why $\mathbb{E}(|X|)$ and $|\mathbb{E}(X)|$ should be different?

One thing you might want to consider: in the example above, what *is* $|X|$?

Comment: Thank you. That makes more sense